# How to pass image src to srcset for the same image using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I have the below image tag

```
<img class="CaptureViewer-image" src="data:image/jpeg;base64 alt="Photo of your document" aria-hidden="true">
```

I have the below image src using JQuery

```
$(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("src");
```

I want to pass the same image src to add the srcset in the above tag. I tried like this

var imagesrc = $(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("src);

```
$(".CaptureViewer-image").attr("srcset" , "imagesrc 300px");
```

when checked for the srcset value , the value is getting saved as imagesrc 300px instead of
actual image source .
I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.Thanks.

Comment: not `"imagesrc 300px"` but `imagesrc + " 300px"`

Answer (score 2):

use [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) :

```
$(".CaptureViewer-image").each ( function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  elem.attr("srcset" , elem.attr('src') + " 300px");
});
```